# Reshaping before and after data

Tags: r

The following data is a very small part from a series of tests before and after a treatment. Right now my data is like this:

```
  Subject Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1   A-pre   25   27   23    0
2  A-post   25   26   25  120
3   B-pre   30   28   27  132
4  B-post   30   28   26  140
```

and I need to reshape it like this:

```
  Subject Var1.pre Var1.post Var2.pre Var2.post Var3.pre Var3.post Var4.pre Var4.post
1       A       25        25       27        26       23        25        0       120
2       B       30        30       28        28       27        26      132       140
```

I have read many questions in SO and the documentations of packages for data wrangling in r like reshape2 etc but I could not find something similar. Any ideas? 
Here is the code for replicating the first table:

```
dat<-structure(list(Subject = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("A-post", 
"A-pre", "B-post", "B-pre"), class = "factor"), Var1 = c(25L, 
25L, 30L, 30L), Var2 = c(27L, 26L, 28L, 28L), Var3 = c(23L, 25L, 
27L, 26L), Var4 = c(0L, 120L, 132L, 140L)), .Names = c("Subject", 
"Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dcast` from the devel version of `data.table` ie. v1.9.5 after splitting the 'Subject' column into two using `tstrsplit` with `split` as '-'.  We use the `dcast` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format. The `dcast` function from `data.table` can take multiple `value.var` columns, i.e. 'Var1' to 'Var4'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
#convert the data.frame to data.table with `setDT(dat)`
#split the 'Subject' column with tstrsplit and create two columns 
setDT(dat)[, c('Subject', 'New') :=tstrsplit(Subject, '-')]
#change the New column class to 'factor' and specify the levels in order
#so that while using dcast we get the 'pre' column before 'post'
dat[, New:= factor(New, levels=c('pre', 'post'))]
#reshape the dataset
dcast(dat, Subject~New, value.var=grep('^Var', names(dat), value=TRUE),sep=".")
#    Subject Var1.pre Var1.post Var2.pre Var2.post Var3.pre Var3.post Var4.pre
#1:       A       25        25       27        26       23        25        0
#2:       B       30        30       28        28       27        26      132
#   Var4.post
#1:       120
#2:       140
```

NOTE: Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

---

An option using `dplyr/tidyr` would be to split the 'Subject' column into two by `separate`, convert the 'wide' format to 'long' format using `gather`, `unite` the 'Var' column (i.e. Var1 to Var4) and 'New' ('VarNew') and `spread` the 'long' format to 'wide'.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
   separate(Subject, into=c('Subject', 'New')) %>% #split to two columns
   gather(Var, Val, Var1:Var4)%>% #change from wide to long. Similar to melt
   unite(VarNew, Var, New, sep=".") %>% #unite two columns to form a single
   spread(VarNew, Val)#change from 'long' to 'wide'
```

Comment: I should mention I (suppose I) had a bug: when a) loaded the package from Cran b) installed from github  c) tried to load the devel package got memory size problems. Restarting R solved this.

Comment: @SteliosKaniballidis  I also do something like that.  I don't know the reason behind it.